# User defined type guard does not narrow the type in findIndex predicate function

Tags: typescript

```
export type Issuer = { comFullName: string; comUniCode: number };

export const isIssuer = (issuer: any): issuer is Issuer => "comFullName" in issuer && "comUniCode" in issuer;

type PayloadAction<P = void, T extends string = string> = {
    type: T;
    payload: P;
}

type State = {
    issuers: Issuer[];
}
const issuerSelected = (state: State, action: PayloadAction<Issuer | undefined>) => {
    if (!isIssuer(action.payload)) return;
    const isExist =
        state.issuers.findIndex(
            (issuer) => issuer.comUniCode === action.payload.comUniCode
        ) > -1;
    if (!isExist) {
        state.issuers.push(action.payload);
    }
}
```

I thought the line `if (!isIssuer(action.payload)) return;` will narrow the type of `action.payload`, it does, but for `state.issuers.push(action.payload);` statement.

Still got an error in the predicate function of `.findIndex()` method:

```bash
'action.payload' is possibly 'undefined'.(18048)
```

If I use the type guard in the predicate function again:

```
state.issuers.findIndex(
  (issuer) => isIssuer(action.payload) && issuer.comUniCode === action.payload.comUniCode
) > -1;
```

The error is gone. But this approach is a bit redundant. Is there a better way? I don't want to use the type guard more than once.

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=9&pln=18&pc=16#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCSBnDBXYU4C8cA3nAMYQC2AYtgDZ0ByAhpcAFxwYxQCWAdgHMA3OSoBVfrwDCEACYc4-bJQBGeOAF9hAKB2hIsMf25xeGTDg1EAFOatROzfogCUne7nzn0WL4QA+OAAiChp6JlZgYLN+Mz8NADJEkLDJGXlo2PiHXR0kFDgABWZEOghmOQBBMhheCH4AHiLCOAA3CF45ABo4ABU4UBhgfjkMLh4BQVbuPiEgomIdOBWEZEU+3VW4MFLyys4i3U09AtQAZRhmYdal7c88DE5LLwBtAF1jnQoTeAeoc7AOjAWrAOStGzca6KS7Q3rMWr1fiHPYVaqIhqNF4aAA+cGwo2AADMBGCAq5AiRlqteES4DYAITmbFQGwIuoNAB0uzKaNcFKgwBg2Cg-C2qx+pnMAFEQOZ4ARqdsVlDhpz-hhOSTRmhCSAbErlds7AkoBSCEFmaa2Rj+NzUZUKckcl5OWkpLIFIQCER2Uj7bzKm6JB7MobthSggBaACM4pWtPpTIwsvlFLuRom0PVps1YGwGAAFjaOXaefs5K541odJogA)

Comment: It's a limitation of TS, see [ms/TS#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998).  The standard workaround is to copy the narrowed thing to a `const` before the callback, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WkzDjm).  See questions/answers linked above for more information.